# ERR! code 127 when trying to use node and npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, cmd, node-modules

Started receiving an error in my Angular application last night while using the 'aws-sdk' package, something about missing 'utils'. I looked around online and saw some people recommended removing and creating a new node_modules folder with `npm i`, so that's what I did.

Since then I've been unable to run any node commands, I even reinstalled node.js, and still no luck. Trying `npm i` or `ng generate` will run, create the node_modules or Angular application folder, but as it reaches the end of the install it throws me this error.

[image: npm error]

I have a project due in a few days that I need to get this working again for, so any help is greatly appreciated. I'm really clueless as to what needs to be done.

---

As someone suggested below, here is the error code.

```
PS C:\Users\lucoz\Desktop\CollegeWork\Cloud\30%\cinema-app> npm i aws-sdk
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! code 127
npm ERR! path C:\Users\lucoz\Desktop\CollegeWork\Cloud\30%\cinema-app\node_modules\@angular\cli
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command bash -c node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
npm ERR! /mnt/host/c/Users/lucoz/node_modules/.bin/../node/bin/node: line 1: This: Permission denied

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lucoz\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-26T15_44_14_016Z-debug-0.log
```

---

Fixed it! For me, I ran `npm cache clear --force`, uninstalled node.js, and reinstalled version 14.15.5 available at this link: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.15.5/node-v14.15.5-x64.msi (note hitting this link will immediately start the download)

Comment: Remember not to show a picture of text. Just show that text, in code fences if it needs it.